# jacoco report in IntelliJ terminal

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I use Maven plugin to generate Jacoco report. I do it by calling below command in IntelliJ terminal:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

At first glance, everything looks fine but the result is wrong! 
Generated file `jacoco.exec` is much larger when using "a normal" console (cmd, bash, powershell, anything). IntelliJ version shows much smaller code coverage which is not true.

Why IntelliJ results is different and why it is wrong? I run exactly the same command from the same location in both environments.
Here is part of my Maven settings:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Maybe try to run mvn with -X and compare the output

Comment: Can you provide a sample project? I can not see why mvn command from IDE terminal could be different from OS terminal one. Do you use same working directory? Same arguments?

Comment: @Andrey unfortunately I cannot provide more code. It is a commercial project and I cannot do this. And yes - I use it from the same working directory and with exactly same arguments. Terminal in Eclipse works fine, all Windows and Linux terminals work fine, IntelliJ terminal produces wrong results:( It is not a big deal because I don't use IntelliJ terminal but one of my team mates have a problem. He can use external console of course but I'm very curious why it happens.